# Condition under which newton raphson converges

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I see in a book that under the following condition *newton*-*raphson* method (for finding the zero of a function) converges:

1) The function is continuously differentiable
2) The function is positive in the left side of the root and negative in the right side of the root
3) The derivative of the function is negative  and bounded in a neighbourhood of the root.
4) The initial guess is in a small neighbourhood of the root.

I want to know a proof for that.

Comment: May I ask you in which book this is given ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Stochastic Approximation by Kushner and Yin. Page 3.